# How to fix initial value TextFormField Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField, which, when users delete the text they have entered, they can currently also delete this initial value. I want to make it so my users can never delete the initial value, which is their country's currency symbol, in the TextFormField. I don't want to change it to a hintText because I always want to show the currency Symbol to the user as they type in text. This is my code below:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
  child: TextFormField(
           inputFormatters: [
             FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,2}')),
           ],
           autocorrect: false,
           keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true,),
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
           autofocus: true,
           initialValue: '${Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).format.currencySymbol}',
           keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
           style: TextStyle(
             fontFamily: 'Lato',
             fontSize: 32,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Prefix text seems to always keep to the left of the textformfield. I need it to be centered where the user's text also should be

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be easy without setting up a `TextEditingController` for what you're asking for. I'd suggest you to use `prefixText` property for your currency symbol
.

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(prefixText: '\$'),
```